# How can I set an element's height in an AngularJS unit test for a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am spec'ing a directive that changes its behavior based on the element's height, like so:

```
module.directive 'contentView', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  link: ($scope, $element, $attributes) ->
    if $element[0].clientHeight > 50
      # Do something.
    else
      # Do something else.
```

In my spec, I want to modify the element's `clientHeight` to test the conditional. However, it always comes out as `0` no matter what I do.

```
# Boilerplate testing code excluded.

element = $compile('<div content-view></div>')(scope) 
element[0].clientHeight = 50
$rootScope.digest()

# This still evaluates to 0 in the spec and when the code runs.
console.log element[0].clientHeight
```

I've also tried adding an inline style to the HTML passed to $compile (`<div content-view style="100px"></div>`), but this does not change anything.

Is there some way I can specify the `clientHeight` in my test?

Comment: The clientHeight is measured so you could append the element to document body and set the height using `$element.css('height', '50px');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to this based on @jantimon's solution in the comments above. The height is also not computed unless contained within a `$timeout` block. I'm not totally sure why this is but I suppose it has something to do with Angular's DOM lifecycle.

Perhaps someone with a better understanding of this could offer a more elegant solution, but the following works:

The directive:

```
module.directive 'contentView', ($timeout) ->   
  restrict: 'A'
  link: ($scope, $element, $attributes) ->
    $timeout ->
      if $element[0].clientHeight > 50
        # Do something.
      else
        # Do something else.
```

The spec *(not including boilerplate for injecting services)*:

```
element = $compile('<div content-view></div>')(scope)
element.css 'height', '50px'

$document.find('body').append(element)
$timeout.flush()

# Correctly reports as 50.
console.log element[0].clientHeight
```